# Word for very long and/or very complex mathematical expression?

Tags: translation, mathematics

In some Latinamerican countries (Spanish speaking) the word "chorizo" is sometimes **colloqualy** used to refer to a very long and/or very complex mathematical expression. This use is almost slang and it is not recognised by the official language academy, [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8zVTkmc|8zXCZBX).

An example of a magnificient *chorizo* (from [here](http://nuclear.ucdavis.edu/~tgutierr/files/stmL1.html)):

[image]

Is there any word to convey such idea in English, ideally already being used in/formally in a mathematical context? Notice that the word "chorizo" is not used as an adjective, but as a noun. As in "the professor gave us a *chorizo* as homework". As such, searching for synonymous of complex is unhelpful. I've tried using [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/complex) without success.

Comment: No, there is no such single word in common use in (Br) English to denote such an expression.  But, following your *chorizo* theme, why don't you call it a *banger* and see if you can make it catch on ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark or 'sausage' (or more idiomatically 'sausage works'), for Americans who don't know what a 'banger' is out of context.

Comment: A special case of this is 'a blizzard of integrals'.